# How does a TeX editor knows what types of compiler are installed?

Tags: pdftex, windows

So, suppose I install MiKTeX in my Windows. How, then, TeXworks know that I have the compilers pdfLaTeX for example, installed?

Comment: Editors don't know what you have installed. They just assume it's there.

Comment: The compilers have a special gift, a sort of binary telepathy.

Comment: When you install the program, the registry gets informed. And some editors scan the registry for specific program entries.

Comment: Continuing what Harish said: at the end of the day, the editor will usually just call (e.g.) `pdflatex` with a special command-line call.  If that call succeeds, great. If the call fails, not to worry (much)—the editor will simply issue a specific error.

Comment: Apart from anything else, this is editor-dependent. For example, some use a search approach based on 'known' install paths, the command line path, _etc._ Depending on the platform, something like `which pdflatex` may also be usable to find binaries.

Comment: Is there some underlying reason for asking this: I'm wondering if this is an 'X-Y' question (where what your really need to know is not actually what you've asked).

Comment: Windows has a Registry (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry( which contains information like that.